# How to place buttons above UITableView (and not in navigation bar)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button

I am new to iphone programming. I am learning uitableview at the moment. I need to create an app that has buttons above table view (but not in the navigation bar) like in this app (recent, support, ...):
[image]

How is this achieved here, are buttons part of table's header? Is it possible to call a function to redraw tableview with new data after someone presses button above tableview. How is it done?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to scroll these butttons with table?

Comment: are you talking about recent in Phone application of iPhone.

Comment: I want them to be at the top all the time, so user would be able to change what is displayed in tableview (i won't have tabs at the bottom).

Comment: @Ravin: My buttons will have different names, this screenshot is just for illustration what i need.

Comment: sorry but I am not able to see screen shots. where are they

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new view controller, but don't check the box for UITableViewController subclass.
In IB, drag a uiTableView onto the view and make it start about 44 pixels below the Nav Bar.
Then drag buttons into that space.  Declare your IBOutlet variables in your .h file, and hook them up.

For the second part of your question: have the button call an IBAction, and have that method call

```
  [myTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: How do you make the space around the buttons to be white though, so when you scroll the TableView, it doesn't appear around the button?

Answer (score 1):

The buttons can just be placed on a green background image (in the above case) above the UITableView i.e. your tableview can start below the green background imageview on which the buttons are placed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your `init` method, or `loadView` or wherever you prefer:

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Recent", @"Support", @"Around here", nil]];
segment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segment;
[segment release];
```

Comment: Note that in this way they won't always be visible - they will scroll with the table.

Comment: If you want them to always be visible you might want to use your own UIViewController instead of subclassing UITableViewController, so that you can resize your table view (and place those buttons on top) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to scroll these Buttons with your table view then you can add them in your IB and add your table view below them. Assign a tag to each button in IB. When a button is clicked then check in your action (that you have specified for buttons) for button tag and reload your table according to their tag.

If you want to scroll them with table then add them at indexPath.row == 0.

And also these are buttons with type custom and and these mages are set to them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually pretty simple...

You have a `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController`, which again as a `UIViewController` etc. as a rootcontroller right? Then in your loadView/XIB you will just make a custom `UIView` with whatever size, color etc. Then you attach a `UISegmentedControl` at this view. And you then have your `UITableView` positioned to the bottom of the custom `UIView`. Its just a linear layout with a vertical orientation.

Then you would have a fixed positioned view "above" the `UITableView`.

And you probably want to use UIViewController for this, if you wonder if you could use UITableView...