# Do you have to use a UITableView and not a UITableViewController to add buttons above tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add buttons that are static (they do not scroll with the Tableview) above the Tableview, but below the navigation bar. As described in this question

[How to place buttons above UITableView (and not in navigation bar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650320/how-to-place-buttons-above-uitableview-and-not-in-navigation-bar)

The answer seems to be just use a UITableView, but is there a way of doing it with using a UITableViewController? or you have to use a UITableView and just make it smaller and put buttons above?

Answer (score 2):

You can add buttons in a `tableView` in any case: just use the **HEADER** of the `tableView`.

In details the property is `tableHeaderView`, and add a view on top of the table.

By the datasource of the `tableView` you can also return an `headerView` for any section.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView)

Comment: I can do that in the storyboard? or I have to do it with coding?

Comment: Also can you have a search bar and a view with buttons in the head? or does it have to be one or the other?

Comment: @Phil you can add it in storyboard.

Comment: You must return a view as headerView, therefore you can put in this view whatever you want.

Comment: How do I return a view as a headerview? do you set that somewhere?

Comment: `tableView.tableHeaderView = yourView;`